# ～することで in a specific sentence

Tags: particle-で

Below is an excerpt from 天声人語 vol. May 5th 2011:

> 地に足をつけてきた人々が地を追われる無念を思う。とことん考える**ことで**せめて悲痛に寄り添いたい。

The editor of this anthology I have at hand parses the `で` as `によって` or `を使って`. The latter sentence means therefore "by feeling for the villagers all the time, I might stand alongside them in their sadness."

But I am tempted to take `ことで` as `ことだ` giving emphasis to one's opinion, parsing this `で` as the 連用形 of `だ`, with this example sentence from [～ことだ](https://nihongonosensei.net/?p=10116) in my mind:

> お世話になった人にはちゃんと感謝を伝える**ことだ**。

The two sentences seem to have something in common, I reckon, but couldn't be sure. Therefore I cannot decide on which explanation to follow.

Comment: How do you see the meaning of the sentence changing if it was parsed like you are tempted to do so?

Comment: @Ringil In that case it'll be in effect two clauses joined by 連用中止形 into one sentence. The first part I take to be "`I should` (instead of `by doing`) feel for the villagers ...", and the second part remains "at least I want to stand alongside ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「で」of「考えることで」is 助詞. 「だ」of「伝えることだ」is 助動詞.